# How Do I Update Only The Required Id Via Jquery, In Grails?

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

I have a view file like this :

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <title><g:message code="User's profile" /></title>
        <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
        <g:javascript>
         (function() {
              jQuery(function() {
                return $(window).scroll(function() {
                  var url;
                  url = $('.pagination .nextLink').attr('href');
                  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                    $('.pagination').show();
                    $('.pagination').text('Fetching more tasks, please wait!...');
                    return $.get(url, function(data) {
                      $('#scrolling').append(data);
                      return $('.pagination').hide();
                    });
                  }
                });
              });
            }).call(this);
        </g:javascript>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Render the menu for the user-->
        <!--check the size of the task so that we can diplay a meaningful mess if userTasks is empty!-->
        <g:if test = "${userTasks.size() > 0}" >
        <div id = "scrolling">
            <g:each in = "${userTasks}" var = "tasks">
                <div class = "scrolling">
                    <span style = "position:relative; left:360px; font-size:1.2em;"><g:link controller = "tasks" action = "show2" id = "${tasks.id}">${tasks.title}</g:link> </span>
                </div>
            </g:each>
            <div class = "pagination">
                <g:paginate total = "${tasksCount}" controller = "tasks" action = "test" />
            </div>
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
            You don't have any unread tasks!
        </g:else>
        </div>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

This works very similar to Twitter site, i/e when the user scrolls down the bottom of the page will fetch more results and this will be repeated. This works for me, but the problem that I have now is instead of updating my id `scrolling` part alone, I'm getting the whole page being reloaded again and making the page looks nasty!

Here is how my page looks : 
[image]

You can clearly see that my *whole page layout is been reloading* when my scroll bar hits the bottom of the page. How I can get rid of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (function() {
      jQuery(function() {
        return $(window).scroll(function() {
          var url;
          url = $('.pagination .nextLink').attr('href');
          if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
            $('.pagination').show();
            $('.pagination').text('Fetching more tasks, please wait!...');
            $.get(url, function(data) {
              $("#scrolling").append($(data).filter("#scrolling").html());
              $('.pagination').hide();
            });
            return $('#scrolling').load(url + " #scrolling", function() {
              return $('.pagination').hide();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }).call(this);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work. It is replacing the previous `scrolling` part and placing the new `scrolling` id over it. Ya there are still layouts getting collapsed.. :(

Comment: There you go. Now it will get the html and append it within the scrolling div rather than replacing the content of it.

Comment: Well this again doing the same thing! Replacing the div element.. :(